# Write a file to a web directory

Tags: java

I know, the use-case is extremly stupid, but I need this for web-programming course on university: I am programming a cookbook and now I need to upload (pic)files to this web directory: http://www.jnks.de/Kochrezepte/PICS/Rezept_Bilder/

I have tried this but it does not seem to work:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.jnks.de/Kochrezepte/PICS/Rezept_Bilder/test.jpg");

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

IOUtils.copy(file.getInputStream(), connection.getOutputStream());
```

Thanks for any hints on this!

Comment: You probably already have access to upload your code, or edit via a terminal. If SSH you can use BitVise Tunnelier or WinSSH to upload a file. Or you have to use FTP access. Normally the web application has to handle the upload access. Programmatic uploading could then be done with apache's **HttpClient**. If you have to program the uploading in the web application, a HTML form would be the starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. The keyword I was looking for is 'WebDAV'

A Java framework is sardine: http://code.google.com/p/sardine/wiki/UsageGuide?tm=6#Introduction

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the error message you are receiving, this might be a little off but on first glance I'm making an assumption that you're using an invalid mime type for the upload. Try using:

```
"image/jpeg"
```

Comment: There is no error messege, it seems to work fine despite the file is not uploaded. But I will give it a try. [edit: nope]